# Trying to find a regex pattern that matches a substring that contains HTML tags

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, match, gettext

Basically, in a text editor (coda) I need a pattern to match all those esc_html__() functions that contains strings with html tags:

```
esc_html__( 'string that contains <a href="#">text</a> html tags', TEXT_DOMAIN )
```

Excluding those who does not have html tags in them:

```
esc_html__( 'any string that does not contain html tags', TEXT_DOMAIN )
```

My goal is to then replace the function and wrap it with another one so it becomes like this:

```
wp_kses( __( 'string that contains <a href="#">text</a> html tags', TEXT_DOMAIN ), allowed_html())
```

Any help would be appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you change the esc_html_ code (or override it to detect the tag)?

Comment: @JanDoggen Not sure I understand what you mean. I need to search and replace in over 100 files. I have to target only the esc_html functions that contains html tags in them.

Comment: I assume this is program code you are editing. That code has function *esc_html_ *. Why not change **that function** instead of all those **function calls**?

Comment: Yes, it's a wordpress theme code. The esc_html__ function is a core wordpress function that gets translated strings and also strips the html. I guess I could replace all those with a custom function that will check if the string has html tag or not. That will be my second option. I prefer keeping those functions because of the wordpress theme submission reviewers, they expect to see those wordpress functions used everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

this pcre (php) pattern should do:

`"esc_html__\(\s?'(.*<\S+\s?[^>]*\/?>.*)',\s?TEXT_DOMAIN\s?\)"`

it should match the string if it contains an html tag, it's not super strict, doesn't check if the tag is closed but it should work. The matched string is in capturing group 1.

You can test it here:

https://regex101.com/r/iF0lN9/3

If it doesn't suit all your needs let me know.

Comment: Thanks ntrp, it works, but it targets more than it should. Look at this:

[link](http://regexr.com/3btbk)

Those in the middle should not be targeted, it's matching html tags outside of the function (). How can I make it stop right after 

`, XT_TEXT_DOMAIN )` 

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is killing me! I wasted so much time on this and still cant figure it out! I surely don't want to replace all those manually, it's over 400 files :(

Comment: I updated the answer, this will match from `esc_html__` to `TEXT_DOMAIN )` so it will match the whole function call while replacing.

Comment: Thanks for your help but it's stil matching more than it should as you can see here [link](http://regexr.com/3btmg)

Comment: I am sorry but I don't see any text in the link provided.. Can you please send me an example from this website https://regex101.com/?